# Why the order of webpacker compiled pack is not mantained? And so the function is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I've a Rails app with webpacker for js & css

I have my admin.js file

```
import Rails from 'rails-ujs';
import Turbolinks from 'turbolinks';
import 'jquery';

Rails.start();
Turbolinks.start();

import '../admin/styles/app.scss';

// load all images
import '../admin/images/init.js.erb';

// load all fonts
import 'typeface-roboto';
import 'typeface-poppins';

// Theme Vendors
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
import 'sticky-js/dist/sticky.min';

// init global theme javascript
import '../src/admin/framework/lib/util.js';
import '../src/admin/framework/lib/app.js';

// init global user javascript
import '../admin/global/init';

// init page specific javascript
import '../admin/page_specific/admin_home_index';
import '../admin/page_specific/admin_users_index';
import '../admin/page_specific/admin_products_index';
```

I need to load Sticky-js before the app init, but in console I have

```
app.js:130 Uncaught ReferenceError: Sticky is not defined
    at _initSticky (app.js:130)
```

If I open the javascript compiled by webpacker my Sticky JS vendor script is at the end of the file, and I cannot understand why. I can move it on every position but is is always at the end.
Why?